# Packaging precompiled binaries inside of a gem

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems

I've got a ruby [web app](http://fractalcomposer.com) that uses [lilypond](http://lilypond.org) to generate sheet music based on user input.  I'd like to move the hosting to [heroku](http://heroku.com) (I've recently used heroku on a few projects and really liked it, plus my traffic is low enough that it'd be free host it on heroku, for a while at least).  However, heroku's dyno architecture doesn't allow you to ssh in and install whatever packages you want...instead, you give it a gems manifest, and it will install the gems for you.

So, if I'm going to deploy to heroku, I'm going to need to package lilypond as a gem.  I've released a few pure-ruby gems, but haven't dealt with native extensions or precompiled binaries, or anything like that.

Is it possible to take some precompiled binaries and package it inside a gem?  Ideally, this would include binaries for OS X (which I develop on) and debian linux (which is what's running on heroku), and would install the proper binary when the gem was installed.

Answer (score 3):

it is possible, since precompiled binary gems for windows are the norm.  Take a look at rake compiler, perhaps.
also https://github.com/rdp/ruby_tutorials_core/wiki/gem  (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/RubyGems) might help
-r

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got a few options here:

You could get the Lilypond [source](http://www.lilypond.org/source.html) and package it into a gem with a native C extension. There are some useful guides on how to do that at http://guides.rubygems.org/c-extensions/ and http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/10/31/dont-be-terrified-of-building-native-extensions

There's also a gem called [gitara](https://github.com/gsmendoza/gitara) but I haven't been able to find any information about using it on Heroku. It might be worth emailing the author and asking if he knows anything about that.

You could create a Heroku [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) that installs Lilypond as part of your deployment. I wasn't able to find any for Lilypond, but there are plenty of examples that do similar things - for example, [this one](https://github.com/12spokes/heroku-buildpack-ruby-imagemagick) installs Imagemagick (which is included by default on Heroku, so probably not necessary anymore - but hopefully the code is helpful). More documentation at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries

Based on my reading, I *think* the buildpack option is the best way to go.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of precompiling, you should be able to just list the gem in your `.gems` file, see the [Heroku documentation](http://docs.heroku.com/gems). Of course, this requires your gem builds the native code correctly - this is still a task, but hopefully an easier one.